# Java Adding JScrollPane to JComponent

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane, jcomponent

Java:
I have a JComponent that draws an image which can be rescaled. I need to have scroll bars that will appear when the image becomes large. I passed the JComponent to a JScrollPane and then added the JScrollPane to the north section of my JFrame, but the scroll bars only appeared when the JFrame is resized not when the image is rescaled. I also set the preferred size of the JComponent but it didn't work.

I tried adding the JComponent to a JPanel first then passing the JPanel to the JScrollPane but that didn't work either.

Here is a portion of my code inside the constructor of the JFrame:

```
JComponent component = new JComponent() {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.drawImage(image1, zoom, this);
    }
};

component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));
JScrollPane scroller = new JScrollPane(component);
add(scroller, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

Answer (score 2):

1. override `getPreferredScrollableViewportSize` for `JScrollPane`
2. override `getPreferredSize` instead of `component.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(800, 600));`
3. `Dimension` that returns `JPanel` must be larger that `Dimension` from `JViewport` (visible `Rectangle` from `JScrollPane`), otheriwse `JScrollBar`(s) is/are not visible
4. for better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, `JFrame` with `JComponent` inside `JScrollPane`
5. add `super.paintComponent(g);` as 1st. code line inside `paintComponent`, coordinates for zoom_in/out to take from `getHeight`/`Weight` (see point 2nd. about `getPreferredSize`)